# How to use document API with HTTPS Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having a rough time figuring out how can I use [this Endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index_) but with HTTPS:

```
PUT twitter/_doc/1

{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}
```

So changing to https doesn't work I don't get any response at all. I'm using X-Pack. Also, I didn't configure any special user.

Any hint?

Comment: its not quite clear what is not working for you. How are you trying to call this API?

Comment: @WillBarnwell Via Postman. I've made a PUT request to https://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype with whatever body and I receive no response :(

Comment: but other endpoints work? for example `GET /_cluster/health?pretty=true`

Comment: You need to make sure to remove the empty line between the URL and the body